# jQuery, navigation-like styled links

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

Take a look at the grey StackOverflow links at the top of this page. The ones that are to the right of the logo. They say "Questions", "Tags", "Users", "Badges", and "Unanswered". Notice how the "Questions" link is orange because you are viewing my question.

I have 5 links that, when clicked, do jQuery things. They do not redirect you to another page.

```
<a class="english"></a>
<a class="science"></a>
<a class="languages"></a>
[ect.]
```

All I want is to add a `selected` class to the link I click. And then once I click another link, to remove the original `selected` class of the first link and add it to the new link I clicked.

For example, If I click `<a class="english"></a>`, add `selected` class to it.

Then when I click `<a class="science"></a>`, remove the `selected` class from `<a class="english"></a>` and add the `selected` class to `<a class="science"></a>`.

Thanks in advance! :]

Comment: You've got the method correct, what have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Cool! Enjoy coding it! Hope it turns out good. Here's the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) docs to get you started.

Comment: I got the addClass to work, but i'm having problems removing the class. I'll post a fiddle.

Comment: Try my example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); // remove all 'selected' classes
  $(this).addClass('selected');           // add selected class to clicked item
});
```

note that this will affect **all** anchor tags. to be more specific to the 'menu' items you may need to use a more specific selector for `$('a')`

**EDIT**

As you're having an issue I created a fiddle of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ak23D/). You can see the text color everytime you click an item.

Comment: Wow, this is so simple I can't believe I couldn't figure this out myself.
Instead of removing all selected classes, I was trying to target the last I clicked with a selector and I don't even know. So simple but this is a huge help. Thank you :]

Comment: It must be like searching for a pencil while you have one in your hand :-)

Comment: Now this breaks my code, When adding and removing the class, the rest of my function doesn't work as it did before. What could be the cause of this? Ugh, I'll post a full fiddle in like 5 minutes.

Comment: Nevermind, i'll make a new question for the problem. Thanks so much :]

Answer (score 2):

When [clicking](http://api.jquery.com/click/) a link, you could obtain all the links in the [container](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) the `selected` class for each, then [add](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) the `selected` class to `$(this)` link that was just clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery methods you need are addClass and removeClass

```
<div class='english selectable'>English</div>
<div class='french selectable'>French</div>

$(".selectable").click(function(){
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/p4sVN/